# keycloak running on kubernetes | not able to browse admin console giving (blocked mixed content)

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

#### Describe the bug

I am running keycloak 19.0.1 on kubernetes 1.21.4
I have one internal nginx ingress controller installed on kubernetes and not exposed to outside, and i have another nginx server which is in the DMZ exposed to external and running as reverse proxy.

1. I used to un keycloak with the option `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true` from inside kubernetes
2. I used to configure the below Ingress file for it to be exposed through the nginx ingress controller:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
  labels:
    app: keycloak
  name: keycloak
  namespace: fms-preprod
spec:
  rules:
  - host: keycloak-test-ssl.stcs.com.sa
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: keycloak
            port:
              number: 8443
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
```

3. I used to define the below configuration inside the external nginx reverse proxy:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name keycloak-test-ssl.stcs.com.sa ;
  location / {

        proxy_pass http://ingress;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
        client_max_body_size 100M;

}
    ssl_certificate       /etc/ssl/blabla/bundle1.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key   /etc/ssl/blabla/bundle1.key;
}
```

Everything is working fine using the http without SSL configuration and i am able to browse the admin console, but once configuring the SSL on the nginx external reverse proxy as mentioned above, the first page of keycloak is loading fine but the admin console is blocked loading and giving the error as mentioned in the below pic.

Any one tell me what is wrong or missing in my configuration would be helpful for me
thanks in advance

#### Version

19.0.1

#### Expected behavior

keycloak has to work properly behind nginx Reverse proxy with SSL

#### Actual behavior

keycloak failed loading admin console giving `blocked mixed content`

#### How to Reproduce?

details given in above description

#### Anything else?

*No response*

Comment: better to terminate SSL at the ingress level, any reason to manage SSL at nginx proxy?

Comment: @Adiii I want only to manage ssl from external nginx reverse proxy that's it. so what is missing here. ?

Comment: >I used to define the below configuration inside the external nginx reverse proxy: why you to define this?

Comment: @Adiii because the external nginx is managing the SSL communication. could you clarify where you wanna reach ?